# Spring for Apache Hadoop using ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am trying to create mapreduce job with [**Spring for Apache Hadoop**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html) which uses **ElasticSearch** as a input/output. I had no problem when I used [**ElasticSearch for Apache Hadoop**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/index.html) library. All I needed to do was add this code to main class:

```
conf.set("es.nodes", es_server);  //Elasticsearch server, default is 
conf.set("es.resource", resource); //set Elasticsearch resource
conf.set("es.query", query); // set ElasticSearch query
```

Now I trying to achieve this in Spring for Apache Hadoop, but it does not work for me. I simple tried to add this to :

```
es.nodes=es_server
es.resource=resource
es.query=query
```

Does anyone know how to achieve it? Thank you

**EDIT:**

I am trying to load data from my elasticsearch server. In plain java (without Spring) it was easy. I just followed [this tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapreduce.html). All I want to do is doing same with Spring. Can I use ElasticSearch for Apache Hadoop java library? Can I use Spring Data Elasticsearch? Or how to say Spring that my source is ElasticSearch.

Comment: This is configuration of your cluster, it should go along with the rest of the resources that you use with Spring. I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do? Your question is somehow not very clear

Comment: Thank you @eliasah for your comment. I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now.